# css form elements alignment issue

Tags: css

I am creating a form using css and having issues with alignment for certain fields. This layout consists of multiple columns
The issues are as follows

1. The two checkboxes are appearing next to each other , instead of one below the other
2. The second column should appear close to the first column, not able to remove the whitespace, should I set the col width for each column ?
3. the html code seems cumbersome, since each column needs to contain the fields based on the required fields, not sure if I am using correct approach , new to css

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 10px 50px 10px
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: start
}

.button-basic {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px
```

```html
<body>
  <h1> Employee information </h1>
  <form>
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="col1">
        <p> Employee id:</p>
        <p> Employee Type:</p>
        <p> Employee Status: </p>
        <p> Promotion Flag:</p>
        <p> Insurance Flag:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
        <p id="employee-id"> 12345 </p>
        <p id="employee-type"> HR </p>
        <p id="employee-status"> Active </p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="promotion-flag" name="promotion-flag">
        <input type="checkbox" id="insurance-flag" name="insurance-flag">
      </div>
      <div class="col1">
        <p> Employee First Name: </p>
        <p> Description: </p>
        <p> Description: </p>
        <p> Promotion comments: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
        <p id="employee-fname"> John </p>
        <p id="employee-type-desc"> HR employee </p>
        <p id="employee-status-desc"> Active employee </p>
        <input type="text" id="promotion-reason" name="promotion-reason">
      </div>
      <div class="col1">
        <p> Employee Last Name: </p>
        <p> Employee Start Date: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
        <p id="employee-lname"> Smith </p>
        <p id="employee-start-date"> 01/01/2020 </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
      <input class="button-basic" type="submit" value="Search">
      <input class="button-basic" type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give the page a purpose with design
try for getting rid of the spaces

```
.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1;
    text-align: left;
}
```

also.. learn about the box model for getting the gaps prettier
with the checkboxes you just need to add a `<br>`

```
...
<div class="col2">
  <p id="employee-id"> 12345 </p>
  <p id="employee-type"> HR </p>
  <p id="employee-status"> Active </p>
  <input type="checkbox" id="promotion-flag" name="promotion-flag"><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="insurance-flag" name="insurance-flag">
</div>
...
```

consider to use a table instead of wiring a bunch of divs

Comment: thanks, made the suggested changes, also added margins , alignment is much better. But the issue remains with the second check box related to insurance flag, it's not horizontally aligned to the text "Insurance Flag". Updated css is below

Comment: body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 10px 50px 10px
}

.container2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col1 {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 10px
}

.col2 {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: left
}

.button-basic{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px

}

Comment: just added one more <br> and now the checkbox for insurance flag is aligned with the corresponding text.